# Xpaths are invalid on Selenium IDE playback

Tags: selenium-ide

I can find xpaths using the Selenium IDE Find button but when playing back the script "invalid xpath[2]" continues to be displayed.  If the Find button can find it I would think the xpath is OK.  The information from Selenium IDE is listed below

base url - http://www.mortgagecalculator.org

open                 /
waitForPageToLoad
type                 //input[@type='text'][@name='param[homevalue]']  300,000

Answer (score 0):

use this Xpath and let me know whether it work for you or not

```
       type | //*[@id="params"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input | 20000
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of FF are you using? FF 22 works but 23 broke. The Selenium team released a new version of the IDE (2.3.0) now xpath works in FF 23.

Issue: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6055

Download: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/